# Unable to add prefix or suffix for unnesting in Polars

Tags: python, python-polars

I have the following code snippet where I am attempting to unnest `metadata`. However, within the `metadata`, there is a value named "`language`" which clashes with the existing "`language`" column name in the dataframe, thus causing a duplication error. I would like to add a prefix or suffix to the column names generated during the unnesting to resolve this, but I haven't been able to do so. Even, putting an alias for "`language`" didn't work. Any solutions would be appreciated. How to Avoid Column Name Duplication Errors When Unnesting in Polars?

**Sample Data**

```
converted_data = [
    {
        "tags": ["tag1", "tag2"],
        "valueNum": 123.45,
        "language": "English",
        "metadata": {
            "country": "Spain",
            "region": "Europe"
        }
    },
    {
        "tags": ["tag3", "tag4"],
        "valueNum": 678.90,
        "language": "French",
        "metadata": {
            "language": "German",
            "country": "Germany",
            "region": "Europe"
        }
    }
]
```

**Code:**

```py
while url:
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        print(f"Successfully connected to the API for URL: {url}")

        # Parse JSON data to Python object
        json_data = response.json()
        
        converted_data  = convert_answer_to_string(json_data.get("data", []))

        # Read existing data if available, otherwise initialize an empty DataFrame
        if os.path.exists(parquet_file):
            df = pl.read_parquet(parquet_file)
        else:
            df = pl.DataFrame([])
            
        new_data = (
            pl.DataFrame(converted_data)
            .with_columns(
                pl.col("tags").cast(pl.List(pl.Utf8)),
                pl.col("valueNum").cast(pl.Float64),
                pl.col("language").alias("lang")
            )
            .unnest("metadata")
            .collect()
        )
        


        df = pl.concat([df, new_data], how="diagonal")
        
        # Save the last successful URL
        save_last_url(url)

        # Save data to Parquet
        df.write_parquet(parquet_file)

        # Reset retry counter
        retry_count = 0

        # Check if there is a next URL to fetch more data
        url = json_data.get('paging', {}).get('next')
    else:
        retry_count += 1  # Increment retry counter
        print(f"Attempt {retry_count}: Failed to connect to the API for URL: {url}. Status code: {response.status_code}")
        
        time.sleep(10)  # Add this line to pause for 10 seconds before the next attempt
        
        # Break if reached maximum retry attempts
        if retry_count >= 3:
            print("Reached maximum retry attempts. Stopping.")
            break

# Read final DataFrame from Parquet file
if os.path.exists(parquet_file):
    responses = pl.read_parquet(parquet_file)
    print("Final Polars DataFrame created:")
    print(responses)
else:
    print("No data collected.")
```

**Error:**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DuplicateError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[238], line 35
      2 converted_data = [
      3     {
      4         "tags": ["tag1", "tag2"],
   (...)
     22     }
     23 ]
     25 # The code snippet provided by the user
     26 new_data = (
     27     pl.DataFrame(converted_data)
     28     .lazy()
     29     .with_columns(
     30         pl.col("tags").cast(pl.List(pl.Utf8)),
     31         pl.col("valueNum").cast(pl.Float64),
     32         pl.col("language").alias("lang")
     33     )
     34     .unnest("metadata")
---> 35 ).collect()

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\polars\utils\deprecation.py:96, in deprecate_renamed_parameter.<locals>.decorate.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     91 @wraps(function)
     92 def wrapper(*args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> T:
     93     _rename_keyword_argument(
     94         old_name, new_name, kwargs, function.__name__, version
     95     )
---> 96     return function(*args, **kwargs)

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\polars\lazyframe\frame.py:1713, in LazyFrame.collect(self, type_coercion, predicate_pushdown, projection_pushdown, simplify_expression, no_optimization, slice_pushdown, comm_subplan_elim, comm_subexpr_elim, streaming, **kwargs)
   1700     comm_subplan_elim = False
   1702 ldf = self._ldf.optimization_toggle(
   1703     type_coercion,
   1704     predicate_pushdown,
   (...)
   1711     eager,
   1712 )
-> 1713 return wrap_df(ldf.collect())

DuplicateError: column with name 'language' has more than one occurrences
```

Comment: Maybe you could [`.rename_fields()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.struct.rename_fields.html#polars.Expr.struct.rename_fields) - if you show an actual runnable example perhaps a more specific answer can be given.

Comment: @jqurious I looked into .rename_fields but it seems to require knowing all field names ahead of time, which doesn't work for me as the metadata fields are variable.

Comment: @jqurious I made the question more descriptive!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know whether or not metadata has the columns then you can check first

```
intersecting=set(df.columns).intersection(
    set(df.select('metadata').unnest('metadata').columns)
    )
(
    df
    .rename({x:f"{x}_keep" for x in intersecting})
    .unnest('metadata')
    .rename(dict(**{f"{x}_keep":x for x in intersecting}, 
                 **{x:f"{x}_meta" for x in intersecting}))
    .collect()
    )
```

Alternatively there's an unnest definition in [here](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/9613) that you could monkey patch which would give direct access to creating suffixes and prefixes.

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work, but why doesn't my alias work?

```SchemaFieldNotFoundError: language```

Comment: language is not always in metadata

Comment: When you do `with_columns` it'll replace any columns that already existed otherwise it adds those columns. So, when you do `pl.col("language").alias("lang")` it just adds a column called `lang` as a duplicate of `language`. If you want to rename columns via `alias` then you'd have to use `select` and list all the columns.

Comment: but the link worked! I think it should be added in Polars' unnest function because in my case I got SchemaFieldNotFoundError: language with your solution because the language is not always in the metadata.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the link in Dean MacGregor's post.

```
def unnest_all(self: pl.DataFrame, seperator="_"):
    def _unnest_all(struct_columns):
        return self.with_columns(
            [
                pl.col(col).struct.rename_fields(
                    [
                        f"{col}{seperator}{field_name}"
                        for field_name in self[col].struct.fields
                    ]
                )
                for col in struct_columns
            ]
        ).unnest(struct_columns)
        
    struct_columns = [col for col in self.columns if self[col].dtype == pl.Struct()]
    while len(struct_columns):
        self = _unnest_all(struct_columns=struct_columns)
        struct_columns = [col for col in self.columns if self[col].dtype == pl.Struct()]
        
    return self

pl.DataFrame.unnest_all = unnest_all
```

```
    new_data = (
        pl.DataFrame(converted_data)
        .with_columns(
            pl.col("tags").cast(pl.List(pl.Utf8)),
            pl.col("valueNum").cast(pl.Float64),
            pl.col("language").alias("lang"),
        )
        .unnest_all("metadata")
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also query the [`.schema`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.struct.rename_fields.html#polars.Expr.struct.rename_fields) and [`.rename_fields()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.struct.rename_fields.html#polars.Expr.struct.rename_fields)

```py
(
   df.with_columns(
      pl.col("metadata").struct.rename_fields([
         f"metadata.{field}" for field in
         df.schema["metadata"].to_schema()
      ])
   )
   .unnest("metadata")
   .collect()
)
```

```
shape: (2, 6)
┌──────────────────┬──────────┬──────────┬───────────────────┬──────────────────┬─────────────────┐
│ tags             ┆ valueNum ┆ language ┆ metadata.language ┆ metadata.country ┆ metadata.region │
│ ---              ┆ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---               ┆ ---              ┆ ---             │
│ list[str]        ┆ f64      ┆ str      ┆ str               ┆ str              ┆ str             │
╞══════════════════╪══════════╪══════════╪═══════════════════╪══════════════════╪═════════════════╡
│ ["tag1", "tag2"] ┆ 123.45   ┆ English  ┆ null              ┆ Spain            ┆ Europe          │
│ ["tag3", "tag4"] ┆ 678.9    ┆ French   ┆ German            ┆ Germany          ┆ Europe          │
└──────────────────┴──────────┴──────────┴───────────────────┴──────────────────┴─────────────────┘
```

Comment: It's another nice approach but as I mentioned not all my files have the same schema, so I get KeyError: 'metadata'. look at the question again and see if you can make your answer better.

Comment: `metadata` must exist if you are unnesting it (otherwise you would get a `ColumnNotFoundError`?). As per the updated question, It would be the schema of `converted_data` e.g. as if you had `df = pl.DataFrame(converted_data)`